# How to determine if checkbox checked in PDF that is not a form

Tags: pdf, checkbox, unicode, itext

We receive PDF files from many sources and have to read/parse the data in them.

In some cases the checkboxes are checked or unchecked and we get those values as Unicode that we can look for and determine if it is checked or not.

However, in some cases that approach doesn't work.

We know the pdf does not have a form of any type, not XFA nor Acroform, so we can only parse from String values.

However, in the pdfs that don't use Unicode to represent checkboxes I am not sure how else I could figure out if it is filled/checked or not.

I am pasting the list of Unicode I look for for the PDFs that do have Unicode for it, and that works great for those files. It is the ones that don't have Unicode for it that I am having issues with.

I have attached an image of one checkbox checked and unchecked that is not using Unicode.

[image: Part of the PDF document]

Thanks

UPDATE: I talked with one of the vendors and they said they use WingDing font, so I need to figure out which character in WingDing makes a checkbox and try to find it in the String. Visually looking at the String in the variable I do not see any special character, but maybe it will just represent it as a space in my IDE.

UPDATE: We still have this problem and it could mean my job if I cannot resolve it.

Comment: So it could simply be a filled rectangle/square vs. an outline-only stroke square?

Comment: @user1567291 If you (having all the original files at hand) cannot easily identify the checkbox, you really think someone merely seeing an *image of one checkbox* has better chances? Those check boxes can be anything, some special font, vector graphics, an image, ... Thus, please share the PDF itself.

Comment: mkl  I would love to share an actual document, but unfortunately, it is very personal private data. But thanks for the answer, I think it could be any of those things and I wish there was a nice easy way to figure it out.

Comment: *"I talked with one of the vendors and they said they use WingDing font"* - If you have contact with the vendors, you can ask them which encoding they use, can you not?

Comment: I did and that still did not help in figuring it out. For some reason when loading the data through iText, there is still no information for us to find out if the checkbox is there or if it is checked.